# multiple session spotify

Tags: spotify, libspotify

Our app runs on a multi audio zoned PC that distributes music to various parts of ones home etc. Does anyone know if Libspotify supports multiple sessions? It appears to be structured to do so , but I've had no luck getting it to work. If so any pointers on how to get it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean simultaneous playback on multiple devices or having multiple session instances in one process?

Either way, the answer is no:

- While you can be logged in using as many devices as you like, libspotify (and all other Spotify clients) will only allow you to stream to one machine at once.
- libSpotify only supports one session instance per process. If you want multiple users logged on one machine, you'll need a different process for each logged-in user.

Comment: Actually, Sonos' Spotify client is allowed to stream simultaneously on multiple devices, which is more than the clients from Spotify can do.

To begin with, they are not using standard libspotify. With libspotify that is provided on the developer website, you are only allowed to stream to one machine at a time. This is however mostly an issue involving business/legal departments at Spotify, not a technical one.